# Python loop through lists and append according to conditions

Tags: python, list, for-loop, append, conditional-statements

I have 3 very lengthy lists (of length 15,000). Lets say for example the three lists are:

```
A    B    C
0    2    3
0    4    5
0    3    3
1    2    6
1    3    5
0    2    7
1    8    8
```

I would like to get all those values of B and C that are where the corresponding index of A is 0. For example if `A[i] == 0` then I would like to add `B[i]` to `listB_0` and `C[i]` to `listC_0`.

I tried

```
listB_0 = []
listC_0 = []

for a,b,c in zip(A,B,C):
    if a == 0:
        listB_0.append(B)
        listC_0.append(C)
```

But this seems to put Python through a never ending loop, even after 5 minutes, I see that the program is still running.

What I finally want is, for example the listB and listC for which listA = 0 will be

```
listB_0 = [2,4,3,2]
listC_0 = [3,5,3,7]
```

What is the correct way to achieve this?

Comment: It looks like you are appending the entire list `B` instead of the element `b`.

Comment: that was my guess as well!! How do I append according to the above condition?

Comment: `listB_0.append(b)` and `listC_0.append(c)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Brobin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3703613/brobin) already pointed this out in his comment: Instead of `b` or `c`, the whole lists `B` or `C` get appended.

This should work:

```
A = [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1]
B = [2, 4, 3, 2, 3, 2, 8]
C = [3, 5, 3, 6, 5, 7, 8]

listB_0 = []
listC_0 = []

for a, b, c in zip(A,B,C):
    if a == 0:
        listB_0.append(b)
        listC_0.append(c)

print listB_0
print listC_0

>>> 
[2, 4, 3, 2]
[3, 5, 3, 7]
```

Answer (score 2):

As noted in comments, you should append `b` instead of `B`. I want to note, that you can use list comprehension instead of loop to get results "pythonic" way.

```
A = [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1]
B = [2, 4, 3, 2, 3, 2, 8]

listB_0 = [b for a, b in zip(A, B) if a == 0]
print(listB_0)  # [2, 4, 3, 2]
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to append the values `b` for `listB_0` and `c` for `listC_0`, not the lists themselves.

```
for a,b,c in zip(A,B,C):
    if a == 0:
        listB_0.append(b)
        listC_0.append(c)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is really no need for `zip()` here:

```
# use xrange(len(A)) if in Python 2
for i in range(len(A)):
    if A[i] == 0:
        listB_0.append(B[i])
        listC_0.append(C[i])
```